# Locus of a variable line intersecting 3 non-parallel lines.

Tags: geometry, 3d, applications

Can anybody help me solve this problem?
Find the locus of a variable st line intersecting the 3 lines $x=a,y=0$ and $y=a,z=0$ and $z=a,x=0$.What type of surface it is?(How would it look in space?)
I had started like this.
let the variable line be $\frac{x-x_0}{l}=\frac{y-y_0}{m}=\frac{z-z_0}{n}$.Then I took the 3 points where it cuts the 3 lines as $(a,0,z),(x,a,0)$ and $(0,y,a)$.Then $l,m,n$ could be replaced by d.r. obtained from any of these 2 pts,then I satisfied the variable line with the 3rd one.But it is not easy to get the eqn of the required surface like this.How do I do it.Also I want to know geometrically what is going on and how the surface would look.If anybody has any intuitive idea of the problem then please answer to this question.

Comment: I would be happy if someone gave a pictorial description or some animation for better visualization.

Comment: I also saw the link but it was not helpful-https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1588532/locus-formed-by-point-on-a-line-intersecting-3-other-lines-in-3d?rq=1

Comment: How was it not helpful? It gives you an implicit Cartesian equation for the surface—a quadric, obviously—which you can then classify using [standard techniques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadric#Euclidean_space).

Comment: This problem deals with several unknown/arbitrarily fixed quantities like $a$.If I follow the method,the expressions would become complicated,there they have an advantage that they showed it for specific numbers.

Comment: There’s only one parameter, $a$, not “several.” That’s a very minor difference at any rate, and really only a problem at all if your approach is to try to bash out the equation for this surface directly. The surface in your problem and the one in the linked one are clearly related by an affine transformation, which doesn’t change its nature. Instead of working out the equation directly, you might try computing the required transformation.

Comment: please write the answer explicitly,I could not do it intuitively

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1588532/locus-formed-by-point-on-a-line-intersecting-3-other-lines-in-3d?rq=1) that you found provides a way to classify the surface without finding an equation for the one in yours. In that question, the surface turns out to be a quadric. By construction, we know that it is a ruled surface, so it must be either a hyperboloid of one sheet, a cone (degenerate hyperboloid) or a cylinder. Observe that each of the fixed lines used to construct the surface lie on the surface (verify this!), so it is a doubly-ruled quadric, which is a hyperboloid of one sheet.

Now, for your problem, when $a\ne0$ we also have three skew lines, which can be mapped to the three lines in the other problem via some affine transformation. These transformations preserve incidence relations, so the surface generated by the three lines in your problem is an affine image of the one in the other problem. Affine transformations don’t change the nature of a quadric, therefore your surface is also a hyperboloid of one sheet when $a=0$.

When $a=0$, the construction in the problem breaks down: the three lines intersect at the origin, so given a point on any of the three lines, the only line through that point that intersects all three is that line itself, so the locus is just the three original lines. On the other hand, if we look at what happens to the family of surfaces as $a$ approaches zero, we will find that they approach a cone with vertex at the intersection point.

To find a Cartesian equation of the surface, the simplest way to proceed is described in [achille hui’s answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1588923/265466) to the other question, which is a matter of computing a certain $3\times3$ determinant.

Comment: Is there any other simpler way.Actually I d ot want to use affine transformation here nor do I want to say what is the type of the surface.I want to do it by just coordinate geometry.

Comment: Your answer was perfect anyways,no doubt in that.

Comment: @KishalaySarkar Using affine transformations **is** “coordinate geometry.” IMO that principal power of analytic-geometrical methods is the ability to generalize specific results by finding families of transformations under which they’re invariant. However, if you want another way to classify the surface, once you have its implicit Cartesian equation, diagonalize the quadric using your favorite method and examine its spectrum: $++--$ is the signature of a hyperboloid of one sheet.